# 'Status' object is not iterable python Django

Tags: python, django, tweepy

my views.py :

> ```
> def responded(request):
>   reply_twt = Reply_twt.objects.all() 
>   for tweet in reply_twt:
>     rply_tweet = home_timeline.api.get_status(tweet.tweetid)
>   return render (request, 'analytics/responded.html', {'rply_tweet': rply_tweet})
> ```

my html:

```
{% extends 'analytics/header.html' %}
{% block body %}

        {% for tweet in rply_tweet %}
            {{tweet.text}}
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

i need to print multiple tweet.text in for loop and even if i send data to html page it is only data on single tweet. how to resolve this . Thank You in advance

Comment: `rply_tweet` is *not* a list of twwets, it will have the *latest* tweet, since you constantly overwrite it.

Comment: then how do i solve this ?

Comment: `rply_tweet = [home_timeline.api.get_status(tweet.tweetid) for tweet in reply_twt]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
for tweet in reply_twt:
    rply_tweet = home_timeline.api.get_status(tweet.tweetid)
```

This means after every iteration you will *overwrite* `rply_tweet` with the response of the new iteration. But your template seems to suggest that you want to render *all* the responses (furthermore it would otherwise only waste resources since you never use the previous responses).

You can thus for example construct a `list` with all the responses with list comprehension:

```
rply_tweet = [home_timeline.api.get_status(tweet.tweetid) for tweet in reply_twt]
```

That being said, if your `Reply_twt` stores all the information of the tweet (or at least the data you want to render), you better simply use these objects:

```
# in case a Reply_twt contains *all* the necessary data
def responded(request):
    reply_twt = Reply_twt.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'analytics/responded.html', {'rply_tweet': reply_twt })
```

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Just return the full list of tweets

views.py

```
def responded(request):
  reply_twt = Reply_twt.objects.all() 
  return render (request, 'analytics/responded.html', {'rply_tweet': list(reply_twt}))
```

Comment: It is not really clear if the tweet (with all the elements) is stored in the database. +1 nevertheless :)

Comment: I wasn't sure what was intended to be honest.. since I thought it was the tweet objects that are desired (tweet.text is used), but, indeed you are also right.

Comment: well I find it a bit *weird* that apparently we have the id, and probably other data as well, but then use the API to fetch the tweet. A good reason could be to check if the tweet has been modified meanwhile.